# Strange copy & paste bug editing Razor markup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In the following excerpt, I am trying to copy and paste everything after `@Html.DisplayFor` in the second line onto the end of the first line.

In the beginning:

```
<div class="display-label">@Html.LabelFor
<div class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(@String.Format("{0:F}", Model.PlannedBudget))</div>
```

I select all text after `@Html.DisplayFor`, including the closing `div` tag, and copy this text to clipboard, i.e. ctrl+c.  I then position my cursor at the end of the first line, immediate after `LabelFor`, and paste from the clipboard, i.e. ctrl+v.  What I get is the following:

```
<div class="display-label">@Html.LabelFor Model.PlannedBudget))</div>(@String.Format("{0:F}",
<div class="display-field">@Html.DisplayFor(@String.Format("{0:F}", Model.PlannedBudget))</div>
```

I suspect the comma in the argument list that I paste, but whatever the cause this is quite bizarre.  Does anyone else have this problem, and where should I report it?

Comment: I just tried the same thing and had the same result. [Codeplex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic) would seem like the best place to file this as an issue.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2010 RTM, or the just-released SP1 Beta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a know issue with MVC3 RC. It has been fixed in [MVC3 RC2](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/announcing-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate-2.aspx)

**Update**: It appears the fix for this issue was mistakenly skipped from the RC2 binaries. For now, the only way to resolve this problem is to [install Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Beta](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=11ea69cb-cf12-4842-a3d7-b32a1e5642e2&displaylang=en).

Comment: @marcind, my first and only install of MVC 3 is RC2.

Comment: I forget, but you might also need Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Beta. Though it should work with just the RC2.

Comment: Thanks @marcind, I'll get that on Monday when I have some more bandwidth and check.

Comment: We're loooking into this on our end and I'll update this thread when there's an update.

Comment: Thanks @marcind, great support from you guys.